# Jaspersoft studio duplicated bar series

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.2.  I need to change the color of a single bar from its series default.  I've found how to create and assign a customizer class and also how to create my own bar renderer and override it as well.

The problem is, as soon as I do this the chart displays a duplicate series of bars shifted to the right and slightly lower on the Y scale.  At first I thought this was a shadow of some sort but the getItemPaint method is being called twice for every row,column combination.

My Customizer and Renderer (simplified, but tested to show same affect)

```
public class BarCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer{
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart){
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        MyBarRenderer newRenderer = new MyBarRenderer();
        plot.setRenderer(newRenderer);
    }
}

class MyBarRenderer extends BarRenderer {
    public MyBarRenderer() {}
    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(final int row, final int column) {
        if (column == 17) return Color.red;
        return super.getItemPaint(row, column);
    }
}
```

I'd like to show images of the 'good' and 'bad' charts, but don't have sufficient reputation, sorry.  Commenting the plot.setRenderer(newRenderer) will generate a proper chart but without the bar highlighting that I need.

Does anyone know how I can provide a customizer that overrides the BarRenderer without getting this crazy extra series?  I've tried a million things and searched with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the day after finally posting I discover the Renderer.setShadowVisible(false); method.

Even though it doesn't look like a shadow it actually is.  Setting shadow to false has removed it.  Sorry to waste your time.